# Another mysql server is already running error on OS X

Tags: mysql, macos, xampp

I have installed XAMPP on OS X and I want to start MySQL but it's giving an error:

> XAMPP's MySQL can not start while another mysql server is running. Please turn it off and try again.

How can I handle this?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should turn off the other MySQL server and try again.

You could open activity monitor (for example, open spotlight (command-space) and enter "activity monitor", hit enter), then type `mysql` in the search field, select the MySQL server process, and hit the 'x' in the upper left to terminate it.

Otherwise you will need to investigate why a MySQL server is already running.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to start a MySQL server through XAMPP when you have a MySQL server that is already running in the local machine.To start the MySQL server through XAMPP, you have to stop the server running in local machine.

Comment: Erm, "Start>>run>>services.msc" on OSX?